# PHP - Insert as draft

Tags: php

I'm building a CRM and I have a list of customers.
When I create a customer, I usually insert it as a draft as soon as the user clicks on "Insert button". Why? Because I want the user to be able to insert photos and documents on the insertion form. This way, I have the customer ID already and I can process the upload using that ID.
The problem here is that we can have multiple drafts at a certain moment.

My question is: is there any better method to do this? Without creating the draft? For instance, using a temp folder where the photos and documents are temporarily saved?

EDIT:
the issue woth having multiple drafts is that at certain point will may have a lot of trash.
I mean, this works for me ok? And it's a solution I have, I just wanted to know if there's a better solution instead of using drafts.

Comment: Why not use the ID returned when you saved it as draft initially to update the next time ? Like if you already have the customer_id generated for the initial draft, then the next save action should update the record with this customer_id than creating a new one.

Comment: Your questions is not really clear.

What exactly do you mean by inserting the customer as a "draft"?

What exactly is the issue with having multiple drafts?

Comment: @ikyuchukov what I mean is when the user clicks "Inser customer" button, the customer is immediately created, even before the insert form. The user can then fill the other info, but the record is already created as a draft with a certain ID - this way I can use this ID to process photos upload and documents upload and other info. I don't know how to explain it better.
I know I can submit a form with all inputs and photo uploads, but I'm uploading photos via ajax.

Comment: @AkhileshBChandran that's what I'm doing. I use the draft ID

Comment: It's still not clear why having this draft ID is a _problem_ though.

Comment: What _exactly_ is the difficulty with the potential existence of multiple drafts? It's not really obvious to us what specific issues we're trying to prevent as a result. P.S. You can [edit] your question please, to clarify it rather than having an ongoing discussion - that's not what these comments are intended for.

Comment: Also this seems like a general process / design question, and doesn't appear to be specific to PHP or involve any actual code. I'm not sure it's 100% on-topic but if it is, it probably belongs under a more general "design" sort of tag, as this scenario could be applicable to any code in any language.

Comment: @ADyson I edited the question.
I'm sorry but I don't usually post questions to Stackoverflow

Comment: Are you saying that people might create drafts of the same customer multiple times? And/or there might be incomplete records which are never finalised? You can use a periodic cron job to clear up stale ones from the database.

Comment: Or if you expect the user to complete all sections of the form in a short time you could store the first dataset in the Session instead of the DB. Depends on the exact scenarios you're allowing for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what exactly you are using to save the customer in the database.

If you are using an ORM such as Eloquent or Doctrine you just need to have the correct relationships between Entities and you won't need to save the Customer as draft, you can just flush all of the information at once.

If you aren't using an ORM, you can still do it in one request, just insert the Customer record first and get the last inserted ID , for example if using PDO, you can use PDO::lastInsertId https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php .

After you have the ID just set it to the other columns where you need it.